# how to create animated background like in smartprogress.do using js,css,html5

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to develop site that has same background animation as in [cool site](http://smartprogress.do) so I need some advice which tools I need to use to creat something similar or is there any open source plugins like this animation?

UPD: Thank you for them who answered me. I was asking about those small particles that are moving chaotically in background of the site i mean. For those who interested it was particles.js the js library that draw such animation.

Comment: The "cool" site is using html5 canvas. Its very difficult to match what is possible with canvas with anything else. [This should](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/integrating/) get you started

Comment: I need animated background of the "cool" site in the most easiest way that is correct(by the way I mean not using like big gif file or video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the source code too and I think they used canvas to draw the background animated, and then I think they have an overlay.

Edit: Confirmed, they used canvas to give the parallax effect.

Have a look at [smartprogress.do/js/graphBg.js](http://smartprogress.do/js/graphBg.js)

They use this to draw with:

```
  <canvas class="graph-bg__graph" width="1366" height="50" style="z-index: 1; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"></canvas>
```

Have a look at the JSON too. I think its what they use for vertex data: https://smartprogress.do/graph-data/edges.json and change edges.json to points.json. I can't post more than 2 links

Comment: Great job finding that!

Comment: Chrome page inspection comes in handy :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it:

- GIF or other moving image as background (must be hi-res, so bigger load time; few options available)
- Background video (another big file; more options; doesn't behave like a bg)
- Framescrolling background with CSS transitions (VERY big file, older browsers give still image)
- JavaScript implementation of something similar (easier to implement, but similar issues)

I've looked through the source of your example site and can't determine what they're using.  It might be a CSS transition.  But those ideas should get you started.